# CloudFlare & PHP mail() function... where do they go?

Tags: php, email, cloudflare

I have a shared hosting account with JustHost, hosting several websites with embedded contact forms that rely on the PHP `mail()` function.

After enabling CloudFlare (via JustHost's cPanel) none of the emails sent via PHP `mail()` are going through. Since JustHost handle all the DNS settings via cPanel, I can't change any settings on the CloudFlare website without disconnecting JustHost.

Emails sent from other accounts work fine, but any sent by PHP `mail()` are not received. Before I enabled CloudFlare everything worked fine.

Anyone know of a way to prevent this? I really only want CloudFlare for the CDN.

For now I've had to disable CloudFlare until I can find a solution. :(

**UPDATE:** Seems this was an error with the php.ini mail from header not being set correctly.  JustHost were able to correct the issue for me.

Comment: Have you contacted your host's support?

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening because you haven't updated your DNS MX records.

Check here for a solution:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168876-My-email-or-mail-stopped-working-What-should-I-do-

Also check here for a more detailed answer on editing MX records:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169086-How-do-I-add-or-edit-mail-or-MX-records-

Comment: But the problem only exists with the php mail() function, other emails are received fine.